# Using redirection operator in child_process.exec

Tags: node.js, sh

I'm trying to redirect my command output using:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var proc = exec('command > out');
```

I think the problem is related to the output redirection.
I know I can use `proc.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./out'));` but, given the design of the application (this redirection would be a special case for one tool in a set of many which behave differently), I'd like to redirect the output using the redirection operator.

The last option would be creating a .sh script which will run `command` and redirect its output to `out`.

Is there any trick I don't know about this?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection operators (`>`, `>>`), and the pipe operator (`|`) are **implemented by the *shell***. So, if you want to use them, you need to invoke the shell.

One option might be to use [`bash -c COMMAND`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bash-options.html).